# ruby sqlite error 'ensure in insert_row': undefined local variable or method 'stmt'

Tags: ruby, sqlite, exception, prepared-statement

I have the following method in a dbmgr ruby class, which I'm using within a loop to insert data from a csv into a sqlite3 db:

```
  def insert_row(aRow)
    begin
    @db = SQLite3::Database.open("#{@dbn}")
    rhash = aRow.row_hash

    stm = @db.prepare("INSERT INTO programs (programName, episodeName) VALUES (? , ? )")
        stm.bind_param(1, '#{rhash["Program"]}' )
        stm.bind_param(2, '#{rhash["Episode Name"]}' )
        stmt.execute()
        programId = @db.last_insert_row_id


     rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
        puts "Exception occured"
        puts e.message
        puts e.backtrace
        
    ensure
        stmt.close if stmt
        @db.close if @db
        
    end #db
```

When I do that on the console after the 1st insertion I get the following error:

```
  `ensure in insert_row': undefined local variable or method `stmt' for #<Dbmgr:0x007f9511050188> (NameError)
```

Initially, I did not use the prepare and bind_params features of ruby for sqlite. However, after some characters like " ' " in the text I was inserting generated exceptions, I read somewhere that using bind_params would clean the input so I used bind_params. But now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stm = @db.prepare("INSERT INTO programs (programName, episodeName) VALUES (? , ? )")
    stm.bind_param(1, '#{rhash["Program"]}' )
    stm.bind_param(2, '#{rhash["Episode Name"]}' )
    stmt.execute() # <-- you're referring to stmt instead of stm here
    programId = @db.last_insert_row_id
```

You've used stm throughout this statement, then refer to `stmt.execute()` and `stmt.close`

Comment: OH MAN. thats what it was, thanks to XCode not autosaving my edits to the code. haha, now I feel stupid for asking.